# earlier logs in Console of Sierra

Tags: macos, console

After a complete freeze and hard reboot on my Mac Pro, I try to find out why.

In Console “Devices” I only see the logs of the last few minutes.

How can I see earlier logs? The only control I can see is a “Now” button.

OK, looks like “Diagnostic and Usage Data” is more helpful. There I see also previous logs.

But what about “Devices”? Are there only logs from the current system start on?

Comment: Devices is mostly about "other" devices, like remote iPhones.